# Did the early greek philosophers, including Plato and Aristotle make use of the Jewish scriptures just as much as writings from India and Egypt?

Tags: plato, aristotle

I'm a student of philosophy carefully reading through the Britannica Great Books series. In our homeschool discussions, occurring each Wednesday afternoon, I'm finding most of the questions challenging but too difficult. My teacher says not to be put off by my youth, but to persist through to an answer. Also, not much is found on the Web concerning many of the authors in the Great Books series. A good example is Nicomachus of Gerasa.  These writers are so obscure (most of the time) that all I can say (some of the time) is, "What the..."  But, I'm not supposed to say that.

Comment: In all likelihood, no. For one thing, much of the scripture hadn't been written yet. For another, the Greek Jewish cultures don't appear to have encountered each other until sometime in the late 4th century BC, with Plato long dead and Aristotle at best an old man but probably dead too.

Comment: I'd go along with Davids answer; but I think the wider culture is more than likely to have played a part. For example the flood narrative appears in the Mesopotamian epic Gilgamesh as well as the Bible; the wisdom tradition is represented by Psalms and Proverbs and was also prevalent in Ancient Egypt.

Comment: Beyond the two comments above, we'd just be speculating... voting to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: I'd like to see some evidence in your question as to Plato's and Aristotle's use of Indian writings.

Comment: The Jewish civilization was a backwater place at the time of Plato and Aristotle. Wikipedia dates the Torah between the 6-4th century BC.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda in the 19th century said that the Greek philosophers were influenced by the Indian philosopher Kapila. But I have never run across any real evidence and any evidence appears anecdotal.

Comment: Came across several references as to Indian influence on Plato. 1) Divine Harmony: The Life and Teachings of Pythagoras 2) Plato and The Upanishads by Vitsaxis G. Vassilis 3) Do a google on Plato and The Upanishads - several more books come up. Some available online.

Comment: Some recent evidence suggest that all Greek philosophers were Jewish. Also the guy who invented the wheel, agriculture, and everything that maters.

Comment: I suggest a read of Yoram Hazony's [The Philosophy of Hebrew Scripture](http://www.amazon.com/Philosophy-Hebrew-Scripture-Yoram-Hazony/dp/0521176670). I don't recall him talking about influences, although I haven't yet finished it. However, Hazony does note that many Greek philosophers had their equivalents of "thus saith the LORD", and to dismiss only the Hebrew Scriptures on this basis is bigotry.

Comment: @Drux, the evidence for Plato's use of Indian writings is overwhelming.  Become, at least, somewhat familiar with Indian philosophy, then read Plato's _Dialogues_.  The great body of evidence is documented in these listed references: _Hindu influences on Greek Philosophy...From the Upanishads to Plato_, 1984, T.J. Lomperis; _The Dialogues of Plato and the Upanissads_, N. Kazanas; _The RGVeda and the Indo-Europeans_, also by N. Kazanas.

Comment: @DarcyDavis From description of book by N. Kazanas on Amazon: "a well-known Greek Indologist who repeatedly considers the thorny problem of Indoaryan origins and finds its solution in indigenism" ...

Comment: I think it is extremely important to note that there zero evidence of ancient greek philosophers making use of writings of India. The arguments make e.g. by N. Kazanas discuss common indo-european origins of particular mythemes (to use Levi-Strauss's term), not some direct contact between these cultures. The travel of thought and ideas is very distinct from written traces. That latter is much more easily verifiable and we do not have traces of that sort of thing.

Comment: There is a Jewish tradition that Plato and the Prophet Jeremiah met once.

Answer (score 3):

A scholar no less than the William Smith, L.L.D. (*Smith's Bible Dictionary*, London: J. Murray, 1863; *Revised Edition: ...Compiled from Dr. William Smith's Dictionary of the Bible*, n.d., ISBN 0-87981-033-5, s.v.: "Epicureans," p. 95) stated: **"The teaching of the Hebrew patriarchs and prophets was independent of any system of philosophy, and it is curious that Greek philosophy arose just after the Hebrew prophets closed their oracles, Malachi being contemporary with Socrates."**  After Malachi, there was a 500-year hiatus to the New Testament.  This was known as the period of the Talmudists (to 70 A.D.).  So, there was plenty of time for influence of Classical Greek philosophy.  I strongly suspect this is exactly the case.  Unfortunately no modern thesis materials or dissertations exist on this significant subject.  No university will allow investigation.  Perhaps something written during the Victorian period might exist.  But, so far, my research has produced very little other than the Smith quote which may go back to an edited version of his original text (1863).  The *lack of information* regarding the obvious Hebrew literary influence of Classical Greek philosophy and perhaps also early Greek poetry (theogonies) and the vernacular narratives (popular Greek myth) preceding Socrates, Plato, and Aristotle is by-itself much more than curious.  It is my estimation that the flow of history goes something like this: (minimally) Indian, Chaldean, Canaanite, Egyptian ***Hebrew*** (revelationally), Greek, Roman, European (maximally).  And, we are told in public school we can't be Juedeo-Christian or "Eurocentric" because such is "offensive"?

Comment: Greetings, welcome to philosophy.se. That's not much evidence for those of us who have no idea who William Smith is.

Comment: Perhaps you need a 'broader' education.  I'd say you are a little too comfortable with yourself.

Comment: I don't and can't claim to know everything. But I do do philosophy for a living, and I've never heard of William Smith. And the quote isn't really saying much... Why should we take him to be an authority?

Comment: @virmaior I'm thinking this refers to late 19c [William Robertson Smith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Robertson_Smith), early comparative religions guy

Comment: Nice try, @Joseph.  But it's just "William Smith" _not_ the orientalist, W. Robertson Smith.  However, both were Victorians.  I love that period in Western history.  The complete reference (I apologize to for not listing the citation at first post) is: **William Smith, L.L.D. (Smith's Bible Dictionary, London: J. Murray, 1863; Revised Edition: ...Compiled from Dr. William Smith's Dictionary of the Bible, n.d., ISBN 0-87981-033-5, s.v.: "Epicureans," p. 95)**.

Comment: Consider what grounds you have for this comment of yours: "No university will allow investigation." I work at a university, and some of my colleagues work on topics very close to this, and if I wanted to spend the next 10 years researching *nothing but* this topic, I could do that.

Comment: @ChristoherE: ...If you might think you can research this important topic do so.  In my readings from a number of college and university libraries, accessible through WorldCat.org, I've found this subject completely present by absence.  Influences on Plato from India and Egypt, yes.  But, heaven forbid the Jews.  Nothing on early Greek philosophy historically influenced by historic Jewish teaching exists.  If you have a source, list it here.  I'll be glad to look at it.

Comment: An absence of sources describing some possible causal connection in no way at all suggests that universities do not allow investigation of it. That's a wild, absurd leap. Indeed, there aren't sources on most causal connections in the universe. And, what about Jews?

Comment: An absence of sources describing some possible causal connection in no way at all suggests that universities do not allow investigation of it. That's a wild, absurd leap. Indeed, there aren't sources on most causal connections in the universe. Note that you are making a significant accusation.

Comment: @DarcyDavis Taking a claim and presenting it as a fact because it suits you does not automatically make it a scientific fact. There are still many obscure findings that suggest the opposite of what you claim. Recently there have been some Hettite evidence that claim that Troyan war occured around 1500 BC, almost 700 years from the latest standard estimations... Unfortunatelly the more ancient the less the evidence. Glossology is a more useful tool when studying ancient times. I would suggest you take a look at `Hebrew is Greek - Joseph Isaac Jahuda - Oxford 1982`. Cheers.

Comment: @BugshotGG Borrowing old, tired rhetoric again? It's a real bore. It's known from studies in the liberal arts (the commentaries and secondary sources) and from the classical texts, that Plato had a great interest in metaphysics. He was consulting knowledge from Egypt and India. This is a known fact. It's beyond reason that he had no access to the writings of the Hebrews. It remains to modern scholarship to make a strong connection between the classical Greeks and the Hebrews. I'm calling on those interested in the Ph.D. dissertation to make the connection. The question calls for real scholars.

Answer (score 1):

There is no textual evidence which shows any early Greek Philosopher-(from Thales to Epicurus) quoting or commenting on The Old Testament.

Both Pythagoras and Plato were reported to have traveled to Israel and the greater Middle East, though there is no reliable textual evidence which proves this.  It is certainly in the realm of possibility that Pythagoras and Plato, if having traveled to the Middle East, may have learned about the Jewish Scriptures and in doing so, may have written about it. However, there is no available historical evidence to prove this.

The early Greek Philosophers did refer to and write about the histories and cultures of the Babylonians, Phoenicians, Carthaginians, Egyptians and especially, the Persians.

Keep in mind that the Persian Empire, was a nearly ubiquitous political and even cultural presence in Ancient Greek life, due to their conquest and occupation of Greco-Anatolia-(present-day Turkish coast) and attempt to conquer mainland Greece. Of all the foreign cultures the (Pre-Hellenistic) Greeks encountered and interacted with, the Persian culture appears to have had the greatest impact and influence on Early Greek Philosophy and intellectual life.  The Early Greek Thinkers of Antiquity were much more interested in the theological teachings of Zoroastrianism....from a philosophical perspective and NOT from a religious or conversionary perspective.